# how to apply std::setprecision while casting from float to double

Tags: c++, c++11, precision

I have the following `float` value that is being converted to `double`

```
float fVal = 0.0f;
double dVal = static_cast<double>(fVal);
```

I want to control the number of decimal places that dVal gets. I found [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision). But, all examples demostrate its usage in `std::cout`s.

How can apply `std::setprecision` here to get 2 or 3 decimal places of precision ?

Comment: Lookup for `std::round()`. `std::setprecision` only controls output formatting.

Comment: `std::setprecision` only applies to I/O streams. It controls the text format for numbers, not numerical precision.

Comment: Also, floating-point binary numbers don't really have *decimal* places.